Infinite Loop with Excalidraw and React Using Basic setState?
I'm trying out some very basic way of tracking the Excalidraw (0.17.5) elements in React, but I'm getting something like stack overflow. Why???
import { useState } from "react"

import { Excalidraw } from "@excalidraw/excalidraw"
import { type ExcalidrawElement } from "@excalidraw/excalidraw/types/element/types"

export function Graph() {
  const [exEls, setExEls] = useState<ExcalidrawElement[]>([])

  return (
    <div className="absolute top-0 w-screen h-screen">
      <Excalidraw
        onChange={(els) => {
          setExEls(els.map((e) => e)) // `map` because it's `readonly`
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

This is the error:
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

This is crazy to me. This is standard React as far as I know, unless I'm going crazy. Does anyone know what's going on over here? Is it maybe not possible to track elements with React due to the way they implemented things?

After talking to @dwelle, one of Excalidraw's co-founders, he mentioned that I might be able to handle this use case with the excalidrawAPI object, which gives us access to Excalidraw's imperative API.
Given that hint, I was able to come up with this example, which does work:
import { useMemo, useState } from "react"

import { Excalidraw } from "@excalidraw/excalidraw"
import {
  type NonDeletedExcalidrawElement,
  type ExcalidrawElement,
} from "@excalidraw/excalidraw/types/element/types"
import { type ExcalidrawImperativeAPI } from "@excalidraw/excalidraw/types/types"

export function Graph() {
  const [exEls, setExEls] = useState<
    ExcalidrawElement[] | NonDeletedExcalidrawElement[]
  >([])
  const [excalidrawAPI, setExcalidrawAPI] =
    useState<ExcalidrawImperativeAPI>()

  const Excal = useMemo(() => {
    return (
      <Excalidraw
        excalidrawAPI={(api) => setExcalidrawAPI(api)}
        onChange={() => {
          const els = excalidrawAPI?.getSceneElements()
          if (els) setExEls([...els])
        }}
      />
    )
  }, [excalidrawAPI])

  return (
    <div className="absolute top-0 w-screen h-screen">
      {Excal}
    </div>
  )
}

